# R - Transforming columns imported with fread() to date with various methods results in a FALSE evaluation of all.equal()

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data set as .csv file that I read in using the fread() function. This works perferctly fine. So far, date columns in the raw input file are stored as numeric in the format `YYYYMMDD`, such as f.ex. 20200131 or 20210308.

Up until now, I used data.table syntax to transform the type of data for a given column that was not "guessed" correctly by `fread()` like this:

```
    library(data.table)
    library(lubridate)
    library(anytime)

    import_by_fread <- function(fp) {
      fread(
        file             = fp,
        na.strings       = c("NULL", "NA"),
        encoding         = "UTF-8",
        header           = TRUE,
        keepLeadingZeros = TRUE,
        showProgress     = TRUE, 
        data.table       = TRUE
      )
   }

data.dt <- import_by_fread(file = "some_file_path")

data.dt[, date_col_1 := as.Date(as.character(date_col_1, format = "%Y%m%d")]
```

This transformed the numeric data in the supposedly date column from numeric to character and then subsequently date.

Now that I intended to speed things up by using the proposed **anytime** pkg in data.table's vignette, I wanted to check whether the resulting input was the same, and to my surprise the methods I used to check for equality of different date transformation methods sayed they weren't. A "manual" way to check this was to extract the particular column from the data.table and compare these vectors between date conversion methods and count the FALSE values from this vector comparison, but there is none. I reckon thus, the two date columns are not equal.

```
data.dt_1 <- import_by_fread(file = "some_file_path")
data.dt_2 <- import_by_fread(file = "same_fp")

identical(data.dt_1, data.dt_2) # TRUE
all.equal(data.dt_1, data.dt_2) # TRUE

data.dt_1[, date_col_1 := as.Date(as.character(date_col_1), format = "%Y%m%d"))]
data.dt_2[, date_col_1 := anydate(date_col_1)]

identical(data.dt_1[, date_col_1], data.dt_2[, date_col_1]) # FALSE
all.equal(data.dt_1[, date_col_1], data.dt_2[, date_col_1]) # FALSE
```

However, when I do this, all seems to have worked smoothly...

```
 # test for euquality of date transformation of all date columns
 lapply(as.vector(data.dt_1[, c(3,5,7,12,14,16:17,32)]), is.Date) # TRUE
 lapply(as.vector(data.dt_2[, c(3,5,7,12,14,16:17,32)]), is.Date) # TRUE
```

Is this somehow related to how dates are stored internally? How can I make sure that the >1m rows are equal after applying either date-type transformation methods?
Thanks

Comment: You are forgetting the `format = "%Y%m%d"` in `as.Date`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include that in here. In my document I used this so much that I wrote a function ```num_to_date_ymd <- function(num_object) {
  as.Date(as.character(num_object), "%Y%m%d")
}``` doing just that. I just edited the example

So I can exlude that reason for causing this discrepancy I am seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that `anytime::anydate` sets an attribute `tzone`, unlike `as.Date`.

```
library(anytime)
library(lubridate)

x <- as.character(c(20200131, 20210308))
d1 <- as.Date(x, "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- anydate(x)

attributes(d1)
#$class
#[1] "Date"

attributes(d2)
#$class
#[1] "Date"
#
#$tzone
#[1] "Europe/Lisbon"

identical(d1, d2)
#[1] FALSE

all.equal(d1, d2)
#[1] "Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"

d1 - d2
#Time differences in days
#[1] 0 0

d3 <- ymd(c(20200131, 20210308))
identical(d1, d3)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

### Edit

Here are performance tests for different conversion functions and  increasing vector sizes.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

fun <- function(n){
  out <- lapply(seq.int(n), function(k){
    y <- rep(c(20200131, 20210308), 10^k)
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      base = as.Date(as.character(y), "%Y%m%d"),
      anytime = anydate(y),
      anytime2 = anydate(y, calcUnique = TRUE),
      lubridate = ymd(y)
    )
    agg <- aggregate(time ~ expr, mb, median)
    agg$n <- k
    agg
  })
  do.call(rbind, out)
}

res <- fun(4)

ggplot(res, aes(n, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot. That has given me a headache for hours....

But both methods should be equivalent at least in the Date attribute right? Is there a method to compare only the date attribute of the transformed date column? It is rather cumbersome if you have to always specify to only compare the date part of the transformed column in the equivalence check...
And handling these values in calculations wouldn't be any different from using the as.Date(x, "%Y%m%d") values right?

Comment: Do you happen to know any "faster" date conversion method from numeric to Date only besides the rather slow as.Date(as.character(x), "%Y%m%d")?

Comment: @aimbotter21 No, I don't. My tests show that `lubridate::ymd` is 10% slower than `as.Date(as.character(.))`. But `anydate` is the slowest.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought it was supposed to be faster... Especially as the argument ```calcUnique ``` for the ```anydate``` function showed promising performance gains (~15-20x faster) than with the default setting of ```calcUnique=FALSE```. As my data.table is rather long, I supposed this feature would enhance speed tremendously

Well, then I am gonna stick to the orignal baseR conversion way using ```as.Date(as.character(.))``` Thanks a lot Rui!

Comment: @aimbotter21 You're right, that one, with `calcUnique=TRUE` is the fastest, see the edit.

Comment: That's great! Thanks! Glad, that your results do support mine. No I only miss how to handle this 2-attribute date column. Can I really do any operation that I can do with simple dates?

To give you some examples, I use the ```yearmonth()``` function a lot to cut off the days-component of dates to allow monthly aggregation of rows, ````max()``` and ```min``` of dates. I am just curious whether the performance gain is worth risking to break my current project setup because the two resulting columns aren't "equivalent". However, it is still both of class "Date"?! I am confused...

Comment: @aimbotter21 With the results above, `d1 - d2` is all zeros. `anydate` returns an object of class `"Date"` so it can be used in the normal way, and it can be compared with `==`, but not with `identical`. See `class(d2)` and the new edit, right after `all.equal`.

Comment: That's reassuring and a treasure trove of valuable information. Thanks again.

I'll stick to the ```anydate(., calcUnique = TRUE)``` variant for converting dates initially imported by ```fead()``` as numeric data to dates, as this gives a performance boost for really long tables with many duplicate date values that don't have to be converted but can just copy the value of the corresponding unique date value having already been transformed to class Date.

Comment: By the way, as a generalization of the algorightm that I worked with Dirk on for `anytime(..., calcUnique = TRUE)`, I also created a one function calcUnique package that you can wrap around `ymd()` or `as.Date()` or even `cut()`, etc. ... https://cran.r-project.org/package=calcUnique

Comment: I am feeling very vindicated by the benchmark though, thanks for running that.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the code from Rui B. to add `calcUnique::calcUnique()` ... which is a generalized wrapper function that came out of working with Dirk Eddelbuettel on adding `calcUnique = TRUE` to `anytime()` ... here are the benchmarks of all six possibilities ...

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(anytime)
library(calcUnique)

fun <- function(n){
    out <- lapply(seq.int(n), function(k){
        y <- rep(c(20200131, 20210308), 10^k)
        mb <- microbenchmark(
            base = as.Date(as.character(y), "%Y%m%d"),
            base_u = calcUnique(y, function(z){as.Date(as.character(z), "%Y%m%d")}),
            anytime = anydate(y),
            anytime_u = anydate(y, calcUnique = TRUE),
            lubridate = ymd(y),
            lubridate_u = calcUnique(y, ymd)
        )
        agg <- aggregate(time ~ expr, mb, median)
        agg$n <- k
        agg
    })
    do.call(rbind, out)
}

res <- fun(4)

ggplot(res, aes(n, time, colour = expr)) +
    geom_line(alpha = .75) +
    geom_point(alpha = .75) +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Text to Date Performance of Different Packages") +
    theme(plot.title.position = "plot")
```

As you can see, `calcUnique(x, as.Date)` performs almost identically to `anytime::anydate(x, calcUnique = TRUE)` ... `lubridate::ymd()` seems to scale quite well, but has quite a bit of overhead.

[image: text to date performance]